# Incorrect dimension matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, dimensions

When i run this code:

```
clc, clear all
%% loading data
% allowed data type xy.txt, where x is a letter (j) nad y is number (i)
for j=0:3
    switch j
        case 0
            variable='i';
        case 1
            variable='u';
        case 2
            variable='p';
        case 3
            variable='q';
    end
    for i=0:15
        name = strcat(variable, int2str(i), '.txt')
        fid=fopen(name,'r');
        data=textscan(fid,'%*s%*s%s%s%s%*s','HeaderLines',10,'CollectOutput',1);
        fclose(fid);
        data=strrep(data{1},',','.');
        data=cellfun(@str2num, data);
        m.(variable){i+1}=data; 
    end
end

%% calculations
phase1 = 1424;
phase2 = phase1*2;
phase3 = phase2*2;

% voltage
u_na=m.u{2}(1:phase1);
u_nb=m.u{2}(phase1+1:phase2);
u_nc=m.u{2}(phase2+1:end);

% *voltage harmonic

% current
i_na=m.i{2}(1:phase1);
i_nb=m.i{2}(phase1+1:phase2);
i_nc=m.i{2}(phase2+1:end);

i_ha(1:phase1)=0;
i_hb(1:phase1)=0;
i_hc(1:phase1)=0;

for k=1:15
    if k==2
        break;
    end
    i_ha = i_ha + m.i{k}(1:phase1);
    i_hb = i_hb + m.i{k}(phase1+1:phase2);
    i_hc = i_hc + m.i{k}(phase2:end); %this line cause error
end
```

last line in the loop, cause error:

[image: error]

Here is variable dimensions:

[image: variable dimension]

Anyone have thought where is the problem? These lines:

```
i_ha = i_ha + m.i{k}(1:phase1);
i_hb = i_hb + m.i{k}(phase1+1:phase2);
i_hc = i_hc + m.i{k}(phase2:end);
```

looks indentically, but only last cause problem. I tried changing end to phase1*3, but this didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

```
i_hc = i_hc + m.i{k}(phase2+1:end);
```

I think you made a mistake in the code.. Just change it accordingly..

Comment: Yes, this is simple mistake, but when changed it, I recevied this same problem with: `for k=1:15
    p_a = p_a + m.p{k}(1:phase1);
    p_b = p_b + m.p{k}(phase1+1:phase2);
    p_c = p_c + m.p{k}(phase2+1:end);
end`

Comment: why data is 1425x3 while i_hc = 1424x1? why is there a difference?

Comment: can you check how many elements there are in m.i{k}(phase2+1:end); is 1425 or 1424?

Comment: For this: `p_a = p_a + m.p{k}(1:phase1+1);
    p_b = p_b + m.p{k}(phase1+1:phase2+1);
    p_c = p_c + m.p{k}(phase2+1:end);` 1x1425, 1x1425, 1x1424.